# API First Design: MERN stack API call

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, mern

I am doing a small project with API First design approach. Basic flow is in my React front end I have a sequence of tasks as part of a workflow. On the nodeJS side I would be executing these DAG
tasks.

Sample :
A --> B --> C

I can design the api as /task (and in it pass in A, B or C and parameters and in the controller invoke A, B or C .

The second way is for api as url/A, url/B , url/C and each one does their specific task.

The second approach seems to be better from the ability to mock it and allow front-end development to progress since it would validate the required params for each task etc.

Are there any pros or cons of each approach or any better/standard way to develop APIs.

===

To clarify A, B and C are typical ETL tasks , A (source connection) , B (merge/join etc)  , C (data clean) etc . Each task is different. I was thinking about the abstraction as "task" in the workflow (and pass in operation : connection/merge/validate and their corresponding data eg : "A" will be operator : sourceconnection , request body will have connection details, table , SQL etc ), "B" operator : "merge" request body will have details of operation ). Hence api will be something like "<base_url/v{i}/flow/. The other approach was  <base_url/v{i}/flow/source (A) , <base_url/v{i}/flow/merge (B) etc .

Which approach is correct or anything better and why is my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Parameters are more typically used when there's one operation and you could have many different options for that operation.  For example, the path might be `/api/search` because search is the operation and then have various search parameters that go with it.  Separate operations are typically separate path items as in `/api/A` where A is descriptive of the operation.  Then, task A could also have parameters if necessary.

Comment: API design is hard in the abstract.  If you told us what the actual three operations are and what they do, we could offer better ideas for which might be best.  API design is also a holistic thing where you kind of have to see the entire landscape of the API to make it all be consistent and make sense together.

Comment: Appreciate the info . To clarify A, B and C are typical ETL tasks . I have clarified it in the question since the comment section had character limit. Thank you for your time.